# Jquery, fadeout div when button is doubleclicked

Tags: jquery

If I have a button and when I `dblclick` it, it should make the `<div>` fadeout.

Again I want the `<div>` to fadeout **not** the button, but it doesn't work. The problem is that the `<div>`  doesn't disappear on `dblclick`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fnt").hide(); 
    $("#fded").slideUp();

    $("button").click(function() {
        $("#fded").slideDown();
    });

    $("button").dblclick(function(){
        $("#fded").fadeOut('fast');
    });
});
```

This is just example code, I actually want the `<div>` to `fadeOut` over 5 seconds.

Comment: make a demo.. www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: if you want the button to fade, use `$(this).fadeOut('fast');` instead

Comment: @user3676086 Please add your html code or *do* use jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

## Update: Answer does not target question any more, due to changed question. Waiting for more information in question before editing answer.

As far as I understand your question, you want the button you double click, to fade out?

This should do the job:

```
$("button").dblclick(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut('fast');
});
```

The problem in your code is that `$('div')` does not refer to the button which has triggered the `.dblclick()` event. However, the `$(this)` *does refer* to the element which has triggered the `.dblclick()` event.

---

Maybe also have a look at [.dblclick() on jQuery.com](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/)?